# Is there a term for the rhetorical technique of repeating an interlocutor's ideas while making it sound like their own?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, rhetorical-devices

Is there a term for the rhetorical technique of repeating, either spoken or written, the interlocutor's ideas or opinions, without acknowledgement, while making it sound like either something new or a correction? This seems to be an ego-, and self esteem-saving coopting technique. It makes it difficult for the interlocutor to disagree with his own position.

It differs from merely incorporating the other's facts, ideas or opinions into ones own narrative.

I have seen this used twice where that person wanted to end an exchange. They did not want to admit they were wrong, but they still wanted to get in the last word.

Comment: As you have seen this (*I have seen this used twice where that person wanted to end an exchange. They did not want to admit they were wrong, but they still wanted to get in the last word.*) could you please give an example?

Comment: I added the tags "single-word-request" and "phrase-request" since you're looking for a term for this phenomenon. These tags ask that you edit to provide a sample sentence of how the word you're looking for would be used, which ought to help. Presenting someone else's ideas as your own, in the abstract, is simply *plagiarism*. It's also a common component of the recent coinage *mansplaining*.